# OSRM snap to road is not working in some cases

Tags: navigation, gps, geospatial, osrm

I have GPS coordinates captured real-time (listed below).I transformed them to the required format to call to ORSRM match algorithm

This is my URL after transformation: http://192.168.13.88:5001/match/v1/driving/-78.8042,39.642;-78.8019,39.6422;-78.8012,39.6425;-78.7997,39.6432;-78.7993,39.6433;-78.7991,39.6435;-78.7989,39.6437;-78.7983,39.6443;-78.7981,39.6447;-78.7976,39.6486;-78.7976,39.6501;-78.7986,39.6522;-78.7985,39.6526;-78.797,39.6546;-78.7967,39.6546;-78.796,39.6545;-78.796,39.6546;-78.7962,39.6547;-78.7963,39.6548;-78.7964,39.6549;-78.7965,39.6549;-78.7965,39.6549?overview=simplified&radiuses=49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49;49&generate_hints=false&skip_waypoints=true&gaps=ignore&geometries=geojson

In response the result I got is :
[[-78.804195, 39.641965], [-78.80203, 39.642209], [-78.802192, 39.642679], [-78.801845, 39.642981], [-78.800656, 39.643921], [-78.800395, 39.644126], [-78.800167, 39.644305], [-78.799939, 39.644484], [-78.799256, 39.645021], [-78.798928, 39.645279], [-78.801483, 39.647314], [-78.798583, 39.650612], [-78.797691, 39.651771], [-78.798057, 39.65209], [-78.79828, 39.65217], [-78.798603, 39.651968], [-78.798454, 39.652061], [-78.79828, 39.65217], [-78.798057, 39.65209], [-78.797691, 39.651771], [-78.796501, 39.653601], [-78.796323, 39.653802], [-78.796534, 39.653613], [-78.796583, 39.65363], [-78.796797, 39.653707], [-78.796929, 39.653754], [-78.796964, 39.653766], [-78.796964, 39.653766], [-78.796964, 39.653766]]

When I plot the OSRM output, map showed totally different route

Input showed on map:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13J47.png)

Output shoed on map:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LLVQ.png)

I guess OSRM don't have specific road information (my assumption).

Question: I want to ask either my parameters selection for OSRM is correct or need to change?
Is their any other way to do snap to road for free in python?